# How Jenkins node match credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For now, I create a node A, but the ssh credentials is wrong. I use credential plugin to save all credentials, they are all in the Global Domain.

I am sure there is one credential which is right to Node A, but jenkins can not pick the right one. Every time i have to manually choose on the UI which is annoying.

I am wondering how could I set default ssh credentials on the jenkins for specific node? or if you have any solution, appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a Unix machine, you can select the Launch option 'Launch slave agents on Unix machines via SSH' on the node's 'Configure' page. Then, underneath the text box, you have to fill in the host address and the credentials you want to use (pick from the dropdown box). You should see your credentials here.